# How to combine two file upload field with different file types into one?

Tags: r, excel, pdf, shiny, rstudio

I have two codes to be integrated to become a system. The system is an Audit Sample Selection System in which I used RStudio to develop the system. The system behaves as follows:

1. User upload Excel file or PDF file .
2. The user click on 'Submit' button.
3. The system automatically selects certain number of audit samples depending on the number of rows of the table in the file.
4. The system displays the selected audit samples.

This is the code for selecting audit samples from Excel file:

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
library(xlsxjars)
library(rJava)

ui <- fluidPage(
 titlePanel(img(src = "kpmg.png", height = 60, width = 130)),
  sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose Excel file', 
            accept = c(".xlsx")
    ),
    actionButton('submit', "Submit")
   ),
mainPanel(
  tableOutput("contents")
  )
 )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$contents <- renderTable({
inFile <- input$file1

if (is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)

file.rename(inFile$datapath, paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep = ""))          
wb <- read.xlsx(paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep = ""), 1)

nrow(wb) -> rows

if (rows == 1) {
  outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 1), ]
} else 
  if (rows >= 2 & rows <= 4) {
    outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 1), ]
  } else 
    if (rows >= 5 & rows <= 12) {
      outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 2), ]
    } else 
      if (rows >= 13 & rows <= 52) {
        outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 5), ]
      } else
        if (rows >= 53 & rows <= 365) {
          outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 15), ]
        } else
          if (rows > 365) {
            outdf <- wb[sample(rows, 25), ]
          } 
    outdf          
   })
 }

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And this is the code for selecting audit samples from PDF file:

```
library(shiny)
library(rJava)
library(tabulizer)

ui <- fluidPage(
 titlePanel(img(src = "kpmg.png", height = 60, width = 130)),
  sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose PDF file', 
            accept = c(".pdf")
    ),
    actionButton('submit', "Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
    tableOutput("contents")
    )
   )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

output$contents <- renderTable({
inFile <- input$file1

if(is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)

outtable <- extract_tables(inFile$datapath)

outtable[[1]] <- outtable[[1]][-c(1,1),] # Remove header from the table on the first page

df <- do.call(rbind, outtable) # Turn matrix into data frame

nrow(df) -> rows

if (rows == 1) {
  outdf <- df[sample(rows, 1), ]
} else 
  if (rows >= 2 & rows <= 4) {
    outdf <- df[sample(rows, 1), ]
  } else 
    if (rows >= 5 & rows <= 12) {
      outdf <- df[sample(rows, 2), ]
    } else 
      if (rows >= 13 & rows <= 52) {
        outdf <- df[sample(rows, 5), ]
      } else
        if (rows >= 53 & rows <= 365) {
          outdf <- df[sample(rows, 15), ]
        } else
          if (rows > 365) {
            outdf <- df[sample(rows, 25), ]
          } 
outdf 
})
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to combine this two codes so that it will have only one file upload fields which could be used for both Excel and PDF files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest wrapping the import process for .xlsx and .pdf in two separate functions, so you basically have `load_xlsx()` and `load_pdf()`. Then just check the file extension with RegEx with something like:

```
if (grepl("*.xlsx",inFile[1]) == TRUE){
  load_xlsx(inFile) 
} else if (grepl("*.pdf",inFile[1]) == TRUE){
  load_pdf(inFile)
}
```

Comment: I have tried the code but this error 'Warning in if (grepl("*.xlsx", inFile) == TRUE) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used' occur

Comment: What does `inFile` look like, is it not a string?

Comment: See my update, I forgot that with Shiny the inputs are returned in lists.

Comment: You also need to make sure the file extension isn't dropped on inFile, otherwise the RegEx won't work right.

Comment: I have tried the updated code and it works! Thank you so much for your help!